# How does datagridview handle "Master / Detail"?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, foreign-key-relationship, master-detail

In .net objects like DataTable when you have two grids(Master and Detail) and add a row to the second one(Detail), The new row will have the Foreign-Key Values automatically.
How can i do it(I don't use DataTables because they suck)?
thanks.

Comment: So you want to implement this Master and Detail with business objects?

Comment: @Aseem Gautam:I use my own classes(I have reinvented everything(everything)) but i am going to have trouble with Master/Detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some articles/papers on how Master-Detail relationship can be implememted with business objects(classes):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/Bindinglist.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581795.aspx

Answer (score 0):

bind the two grids to the respective master/detail database tables and set the corresponding primary/foreign key fields using the DataKeyNames attributes

Comment: it's an attribute of the GridView class if that's what you using to render your data